# I would like to display array values in specific rows in html table inside jQuery. I am having A to Z rows & values were not present in all rows

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I have A-Z rows. I need to fetch & display data based on the Alphabets (only if data is present in DB for the particular alphabet). Or else the particular Alphabet row needs to be empty. See Image below.

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnseV.png)

[I expect to Fetch & Display data based on the alphabets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpXpu.png)

I tried below code.

```
<table id="dynamicTbl" class="table">
<script>
var i=1; var rowCount = 0; 
$(document).ready(function(){    
  for (var i = 66; i <= 89; i++) { rowCount++; 
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mQry)) { ?>
    $('#dynamicTbl').append('<tr class="trtickets" id="' + rowCount + '">' +
      '<td width="9%"><input type="text" id="' + String.fromCharCode(i) + 'code" name="Code[]" value="<?php echo $row['Code']; ?>" placeholder="Code" class="form-control navn" onchange="DupCodeVal()" /><span class="message"></span><input type="hidden" name="Mitem[]" value="M1023' + String.fromCharCode(i) + '" /></td>' +
      '<td width="51%"><textarea rows="1" id="' + String.fromCharCode(i) + 'desc" name="Descrip[]" value="<?php echo $row['Descrip']; ?>" placeholder="Description" class="form-control"></textarea></td>' +
    '</tr>');
    <?php } ?>
  }
});
</script>
</table>
```

Please let me know the solution & what mistakes I did.

Comment: Why not just use an ordered list with alpha as marking type? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#type

Comment: `rowCount` is going to be run after the `fetch` you know right? PHP/server side runs **then** JS/client side runs.

Comment: You shouldn't have a JavaScript loop around the PHP code. Create the table rows in PHP.

Comment: I used Drag & Drop Table rows options here which require js loop